# How to use qt webassembly in qml application

Tags: qt, qml, webassembly

I am beginner in web assenbly and I want to use qt webassembly in qml application. I use emsdk 1.38.30-64bit to compile qml application and it compile successfully but when I use emsdk 1.38.30-64bit with thread flag in my browser I get downloading/compiling. what is my mistake and how should I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you want to use it? What does _"could not compile"_ mean? Did you read [Qt for WebAssembly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html)?

Comment: when it wants to load qml it could not. in web page it shows downloading. when I comment qml load, it could run successfully.

Comment: in my browser I get downloading/compiling

Answer (score 0):

Qt multi-thread support is still quite in development, a single thread application should be in general fine for QML apps, the QML engine is still single threaded. Try also newer emscripten compilers, but even in my extensive testing with versions 1.39+ multi-thread was an issue. Quick note if you want to test your QML app in the browser, you can use Felgo WebEditor for quick snippet testing https://felgo.com/web-editor or you can test our fully fledged web IDE https://ide.felgo.com